# handling roots in mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, algebraic-manipulation, algebra

I am looking for the solution of:

$\text{Solve}\left[-\frac{\alpha }{\sqrt{1-L}}-\frac{L t}{2}=-\alpha -2,L,Reals,\text{Assumptions}\to 0\leq \alpha \&\& 0<t\right]$

Mathematica is giving me:

$\left\{\left\{L\to \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^3 t^2+\text{$\#$1}^2 \left(-t^2-4 \alpha  t-8 t\right)+\text{$\#$1} \left(4 \alpha ^2+16 \alpha +4 \alpha  t+8 t+16\right)-16 \alpha -16\&,1\right]\right\}\right\}$

Now I tried searching what is with all the # and honestly I don't understand it completely, the thing is from my equation I need $L$ as an algebraic function of $t$. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As roots of polynomials can not always be written by radicals MMA defines root objects, that symbolizes the accurate root of a polynoimial. If you want a numerical approximation, use "Normal".

Comment: You can also try [`ToRadicals`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals.html).

Comment: Thank you @RohitNamjoshi

Comment: Thank you @Artes, yes that cleared some of my doubts about Roots in mathematica